# Angular Select ng-model not working (trying to get default item selected)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following markup:

```
            <div ng-repeat="department in storeData.departments">
                <p>{{department.currentManager.fullName}}</p>
                <select ng-model="department.currentManager" ng-options="user.fullName for user in department.users"></select>
            </div>
```

With the following data model:

```
department : {
     currentManager: {
           fullName: 'bob',
           id: '2'
          }
     users: [
             {
           fullName: 'mike',
           id: '1'
           },
           {
           fullName: 'bob',
           id: '2'
           }
           {
           fullName: 'jeff',
           id: '3'
           }
          ]
```

yet the default option for the select is always blank.  Is this because the ng-model is not directly in the options array?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the value of `department.currentManager` when the selected option is blank? Perhaps you need to assign it a value.

Comment: @abstractpaper a blank or default option would be fine there.  I tried setting a default option value but that didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <select ng-model="department.currentManager" ng-options="user.fullName for user in department.users"></select>
> ```

Replace To

> ```
> <select ng-model="department.currentManager.id" ng-options="user.id as user.fullName for user in department.users"></select>
> ```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VDDCn/)**

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

```
ng-options="user as user.fullName for user in department.users"

department.currentManager = department.users[1];
```

Or

```
ng-options="user.fullName for user in department.users"

department.currentManager = "bob";
```

Comment: I have the object on hand, not the index within the array.  Are you telling me I have to iterate over the array, find the user that matches the currentManager's id, and then set that index?  That seems really messy.